# Check for div's with a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I have a bunch of div's that I have set to animate at the moment.  However I am wanting a way that if they've been animated (Their width would have changed from 100px to 300px for example)  they won't reanimate when I click on them again.  I'm new to javascript & jquery so I'm unsure how to check the width of a div element to place in an if statement.  If I need to post the code I can if requested. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('selector')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).width() < 300; })
    .animate(...);
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful! Also this link helped me along with this answer for future visitors to this question -- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 2):

You should add a class to all elements you want to animate

```
<div class="animateMe something something"> 
content
</div>
```

and in jQuery

```
$('div.animateMe').animate({animate params},duration,function(){
     $(this).removeClass('animateMe');
});
```

this will act as a flag and once animation has been done, it wont happen again on same element irrespective of height and width.

**Advantage:**
Your code will not depend upon height/width params. if tomorrow animation changes and your blocks animate to a different height/width, this code will still be valid.

syntax for animate is **jQuery.animate({animation params}, duration, callback)**;

***Caution**: Don't use the animateMe class for styling*

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
if($(".bunch-of-divs-class").width() == something)
{
     //Do Something
}
```

Comment: I don't think so - `width()` here will just return the width of the first div.

Comment: This is incorrect as `$(".bunch-of-divs-class").width()` returns an array and thus not realistic as you would have to update something whenever you changed the divs. `.filter()` is better.